# How to repeat/loop/return to a class

Tags: java, loops, system, return, repeat

Im a beginner with java and i am following tutorials by Thenewboston on youtube.  I wanted to go to a bit more advanced (in my opinion... but not really) things.  So heres the code.  I want to make it so that it repeats to the beginning so i can enter another number without restarting the program.  I believe i have to use the return command but i am not sure where and how to.  Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class apples {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner alex = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double test;
        test = alex.nextDouble();

        if (test == 9) {
            System.out.println("eat");
        } else {
            System.out.println("do not eat");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class apples{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner alex = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double test;
        while(true) {
            test = alex.nextDouble();
            if (test == 9){
                System.out.println("eat");
            }else{
                System.out.println("do not eat");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  What does the while(true) statement mean though?

Comment: That means "keep repeating forever"; while(condition) {statements} will execute "statements" until "condition" becomes false

Comment: true is always true, So your program will keep taking input until you kill it :)

Answer (score 1):

like in C or C++ you could use a while statement , askin after the execution is the user want go to exit or not

```
while (answer){
  // ...code...
}
```

also you could use do..while

```
do{
  // ...code...
}while(condition)
```

Comment: can you be more elaborate?  like i said before, im a beginner.  I have no experience with c or c++.  Where should i put while and what should the code and condition be?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code around `while` loop and use `break` to come out of loop if your condition is true.

```
while((alex.hasNext()))
   {
    test = alex.nextDouble();

    if (test == 9){
        System.out.println("eat");
        break;

}else{
        System.out.println("do not eat");


}
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Double test;
Scanner alex = new Scanner(System.in);
  while (alex.hasNextDouble()) {
     test = alex.nextDouble();
         if (test == 9){
              System.out.println("eat");
               continue;

          }else{
                 System.out.println("do not eat");
                  break;

     }

  }
```

Note: Assuming all inputs are double, otherwise this program may fail.

This is not perfect example too, because even though you don't say continue while loop iterates. It may be good example for break.